# Inertial frames and Sagnac interferometers

Tags: gravity, laser

Let's posit:

- I am in orbit around a large body, like a planet, and
- I am close enough to be tidally locked to the large body.

Am I in an inertial frame?  Even without looking at the stars, couldn't I measure my rotation with a Sagnac interferometer?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagnac_effect

As I rotate once per rotation, one leg of the interferometer would travel more than the other, and I could see the change in the interference pattern.

This is surprising to me, because I thought that, if I were in freefall, I would perceive myself in an inertial frame, but in this case it seems not.

Obviously, I am misunderstanding part of this; can someone explain my confusion away?

Comment: [More on the Sagnac effect](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+sagnac).

Comment: You are thinking too Newtonian. Inertial frames in general relativity have no extent. They are infinitesimally small.

Comment: Relativistic frames of reference having infinitesimal extent does indeed resolve all of my difficulties.  Thanks!

Comment: Very good question. I don’t feel qualified to say in answer form what I will say in this comment. The Sagnac interferometer provides evidence that is in conflict with relativity.